# Android - Camera Preview

Tags: android, camera, preview

i'm trying the camera preview

This is my code and it doesn't throw any error, but the screen is still black.  Any ideas?

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.camerapreview);    
SurfaceView cameraSurface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cpPreview);
SurfaceHolder holder = cameraSurface.getHolder();
holder.addCallback(this);
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
this.camera = Camera.open();
this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
this.camera.startPreview();
```

camerapreview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cpPreview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    </SurfaceView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are calling the last three lines too early. You have to wait for the surface to be prepared before calling `setPreviewDisplay()` and you have to wait for the surface to be sized (`surfaceChanged()`) before calling `startPreview()`. [This project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/) has what you need.

Comment: That works great. Additional question. On Android 2.3 and 3.0 the preview seems to be skewed when we rotate the device. Do you happen to have a solution for this too?

Comment: @NileshPawar: I do not know what you mean by "skewed" in this situation. FWIW, my current camera work is at: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

Comment: Oh wow. the Camera-demov9 from your new code solved the issue!! I will obtain a diff of what i was doing different and post it here for the benefit of everyone. Sad that Google documentaion is obscure in these areas.

Comment: The getBestPreviewSize function is not entirely correct. Example for a configuration as follows this function returns 640x480 as the best preview size causing the preview to be skewed. It should give the nearest good value as 864 x 480. Below is log of the avilable preview sizes , my devices display size and the return value from getBestPreviewSize() function.

Comment: ------------Available Preview sizes------------------
PREVIEW Widt: 1280 Height: 720
PREVIEW Widt: 864 Height: 480
PREVIEW Widt: 640 Height: 480
PREVIEW Widt: 480 Height: 320
PREVIEW Widt: 352 Height: 288
PREVIEW Widt: 320 Height: 240
PREVIEW Widt: 176 Height: 144
-----------------------------------------
DISPLAY SIZE: Width: 854 Height: 480
GET BEST PREVIEW SIZE FOR : 854 Height: 480
BEST PREVIEW SIZE = Width: 640 Height: 480

Comment: I modified my getBestPreviewSize()  function to use the distance formula in co-ordinate geometry to calculate the best possible preview size. this one solved the issue above.

Comment: @NileshPawar: Yes, my old `getBestPreviewSize()` algorithm was weak.

Comment: nvm. Your working code helped me spot the problem in my code.